# Can't use "zoo" package (Windows 10 behind firewall)

Tags: r, package, firewall, zoo

I reinstalled R and my favorite packages this week on my new work computer. I could most install of what I need, but I'm having trouble with the `zoo` package.

**Installation**
`install.packages("zoo")` didn't initially work for me. Unfortunately I don't have the initial error message anymore. The reason is that I managed to install it like this:
`install.packages("zoo", dependencies=TRUE, repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')`

**Loading package**

Here's my error:

```
> library("zoo")


 Fehler: Paket ‘zoo’ ist für 'arch=x64' nicht installiert

This probably has to do with my machine's 64 bit architecture and the corresponding R installation.

  [1]: http://zoo.r-forge.r-project.org/
```

**Details:**

If I now type `install.packages("zoo")`, I get:

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Me/OneDrive - Company/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
versuche URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/zoo_1.8-8.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1094522 bytes (1.0 MB)
downloaded 1.0 MB

package ‘zoo’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot delete reparse point 'C:\Users\Me\OneDrive - Company\Documents\R\win-library\4.0/zoo/libs', reason 'There is a mismatch between the tag specified in the request and the tag present in the reparse point'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot remove prior installation of package ‘zoo’
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot delete reparse point 'C:\Users\Me\OneDrive - Company\Documents\R\win-library\4.0/zoo/libs', reason 'There is a mismatch between the tag specified in the request and the tag present in the reparse point'
Warning in install.packages :
  restored ‘zoo’

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpgPMQFU\downloaded_packages
```

And the session info:

```
> sessioninfo::session_info()
- Session info -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
 os       Windows 10 x64              
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio                     
 language (EN)                        
 collate  German_Germany.1252         
 ctype    German_Germany.1252         
 tz       Europe/Berlin               
 date     2021-02-05                  

- Packages ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 package     * version date       lib source        
 assertthat    0.2.1   2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
 cli           2.3.0   2021-01-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
 digest        0.6.27  2020-10-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
 evaluate      0.14    2019-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
 glue          1.4.2   2020-08-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
 htmltools     0.5.1.1 2021-01-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
 knitr         1.31    2021-01-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
 rlang         0.4.10  2020-12-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
 rmarkdown     2.6     2020-12-14 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
 sessioninfo   1.1.1   2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
 tinytex       0.29    2021-01-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
 withr         2.4.1   2021-01-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
 xfun          0.20    2021-01-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
 yaml          2.2.1   2020-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)

[1] C:/Users/Me/OneDrive - Company/Documents/R/win-library/4.0
[2] C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.3/library
```

Comment: Looks like a windows issue, perhaps [this](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/fix-unexpected-error-keeping-deleting-file) helps

Comment: Installing R packages into One Drive can cause issues - this may be related to your problems based on your installation directory name ("C:/Users/Me/OneDrive - Company/Documents/R/win-library/4.0"). The link @waldi suggested may help fix the issue. One possible solution/workaround is to try `remove.packages("zoo")` then install Rtools40 from https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/, then try `install.packages("zoo", type = "source")`

Comment: are you installing the packages in a onedrive folder?

Comment: I tried the above steps but it didn't resolve it. If the "One Drive" location is to blame, should I reinstall my R version outside it?