# installing and removing odbc R package on Windows 10

Tags: r, odbc, install.packages

I am trying to install odbc R package.

```
install.packages('odbc')
```

generates:

```
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/odbc_1.3.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1319460 bytes (1.3 MB)
downloaded 1.3 MB

package ‘odbc’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot delete reparse point 'C:\Users\some_user\OneDrive - some_place\Documents\R\R-4.0.2\library/odbc/R', reason 'There is a mismatch between the tag specified in the request and the tag present in the reparse point'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot remove prior installation of package ‘odbc’
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot delete reparse point 'C:\Users\some_user\OneDrive - some_place\Documents\R\R-4.0.2\library/odbc/R', reason 'There is a mismatch between the tag specified in the request and the tag present in the reparse point'
Warning in install.packages :
  restored ‘odbc’

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\some_user\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpkxsb1x\downloaded_packages
```

I tried to search some bits from the above message, but with little luck.

I also tried

```
remove.packages('odbc')
```

but got back:

```
Removing package from ‘C:/Users/some_user/OneDrive - some_place/Documents/R/R-4.0.2/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Error in remove.packages : there is no package called ‘odbc’
```

Here is my R version

```
> version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          4                           
minor          0.2                         
year           2020                        
month          06                          
day            22                          
svn rev        78730                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
nickname       Taking Off Again
```

I am on Windows 10.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Looks similar to [this](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/fix-unexpected-error-keeping-deleting-file). Perhaps [this helps](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/fix-unexpected-error-keeping-deleting-file). I tend to always work with R on local drives : less problems.

Comment: R will do that when there are DLLs involved in a package and R has already loaded it; I've found this to be the case even if I `detach` the package. Restart R *without* loading a project's `.Rdata` and try to install it.

Comment: @r2evans, I rebooted computer, opened fresh R session without loading any projects, but still the same error.

Comment: I meant [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66060778/13513328) link in my previous comment : also a OneDrive pb

Comment: I never "install" a package to a not-perfectly-local directory/drive, and I've found that many people have problems on onedrive mounts that mimic what I would expect from network drives. If you don't need the packages installed onto onedrive, don't use that directory, period. If you must, though, use my [`with_local_libpath`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59814948/3358272) function.

Comment: @r2evans, yes, I have a feeling that onedrive is locking files improperly. I have seen similar problems with tensorflow and dropbox.

Comment: (If you already have `withr` installed, you may be able to use its [`withr::with_libpaths`](https://withr.r-lib.org/reference/with_libpaths.html) as well, same premise.)